# When was the british rail strike when the workers fought by following the regulations?

Tags: 20th-century, britain, railroads

I once heard about a strike in british railways. The workers decided to follow strictly the law regulations and that created chaos and that's how they proved the law was wrong.

I can't find any information about it now. Anyone knows any dates or resources? Maybe I remember it wrong and it wasn't in Great Britain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The kind of strike you are talking about is called [work-to-rule](http://www.workplaceinfo.com.au/industrial-relations/industrial-action/#work%20to%20rule), and is not limited to any single action in one country. Here's an article about a [British teacher's union using the tactic](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/education/educationnews/9533544/Teachers-to-work-to-rule-in-bitter-row-over-pay.html) in 2012.

I first heard about it being used by aussies, but its [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work-to-rule) implies (without any backup that I can see) that it is known to be a favored tactic in Italy.

Comment: Exactly, UCU academic union is implementing work-to-rule right now here in UK (Nov 2013) following the one day strike last week and this is a very common tactic.